# Is possible to check the height of td in active admin page, before page load?

Tags: css, activeadmin

In my application i am using active admin gem which automatically creates a index page. I want to check the height of my td's before that index page loaded is possible to that? I have custom active admin styles sheet.

Comment: Can you describe the feature in more detail? There are many factors that influence the height of elements, many of them cannot be controlled like font size.

Comment: Actually i want to restrict the td's height. Some of my cell contains more data.So i want know the height of the td before that page loaded. By getting the height i can call some class to restrict that height and apply some styles.

Comment: It sounds ambiguous which TD you are referencing. Did you mean TDs in the index table? If so why don't you just set a fixed height to TD?